# How to send firebase auth tokens to backend server?

Tags: ajax, firebase, https, firebase-authentication

I want to identify currently signed-in user on my nodejs server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, I have to send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS.

As in firebase docs

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

If the token is sent to the backend server using AJAX post request then what should be the URL in xhr request `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('POST', url , true);` and how to recieve it on nodejs backend server app.js file.

Or there is any other method to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an authorization header in request and parse the header value in your nodejs app.
`xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', firebaseTokenId);`

In your nodejs application you can do:

```
 function abc(req, res) {
     authHeader = req.get('authorization');
 }
```

Comment: can you tell me to which url this post request be made? I am getting error  `POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)`